# Ajax form not submit

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax form not submit.
Is this wrong? please expain

```
function send_enquiry(url)
{
    if(document.sendenquiry.onsubmit())
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"send.php",
               data:'url='+url+'&action=service_enquiry&name='+$('#name').val()+'&mail='+$('#email').val()+'&phone='+$('#phone').val()+'&msg='+$('#msg').val(),
               success:function(html)
          {
        if(html=='true')
        {
          $('#process').html('');
          alert('Message has been sent to the advertiser !!');
          div_hide();
        }
          },
          beforeSend:function()
          {
        var ajax_image = "<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...'     style='width:18px; height:18px;' />";
        $('#process').html(ajax_image);     
          }
        })
      }
  }
```

Ajax form not submit.

Comment: Check your browser's console for the errors.

Comment: your data is in the format of var data = {"name":"John Doe",val:somedata}

Comment: Check console it Response null

Comment: what is return type ? what you are comparing is string `html=='true'`

Comment: Change the way you passing data as suggested by @saty

Comment: echo 'true'; is return  from send.php

Comment: @chandana show the form and ajax file as well.

Comment: where you call `send_enquiry()` function, please show code, and it should`document.form_id.sendenquiry.onsubmit()` although the ajax code should in `onsubmit()` callback function not in if-condition

Comment: After send form only working  beforeSend:function()
          {
        var ajax_image = "<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...'     style='width:18px; height:18px;' />";
        $('#process').html(ajax_image);     
          }

Comment: <form action="" id="sendenquiry" method="post" name="sendenquiry">

Comment: Data passing correctly. Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
action service_enquiry
mail fbfb@gmail.com
msg 56456
name bfb
phone 5565
url fresh-company-registration-430
Source
url=fresh-company-registration-430&action=service_enquiry&name=bfb&mail=fbfb@gmail.com&phone=5565&msg=56456
problem is success msg not display

Comment: i got answer my self .problem jquery library called before send fucntion

Comment: Thanks for all to help

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
data:'url='+url+'&action=service_enquiry&name='+$('#name').val()+'&mail='+$('#email').val()+'&phone='+$('#phone').val()+'&msg='+$('#msg').val(),
```

to

```
data:{url:url,action:service_enquiry,name:('#name').val(),mail:('#email').val(),phone:$('#phone').val(),msg:$('#msg').val()},
```

Comment: I think problem is  /data:'url='+url+'&action=service_enquiry&name='+$('#name').val()+'&mail='+$('#email').val()+'&phone='+$('#phone').val()+'&msg='+$('#msg').val(), this line

Comment: data:{url:url,action:service_enquiry,name:$('#name').val(),mail:$('#email').val(),phone:$('#phone').val(),msg:$('#msg').val()},????

Comment: what error do you see in the console, and the format of posting the data in ajax is the one that i showed you in my answer

Comment: i did line change but no results in console but previously HeadersPostResponse
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
action service_enquiry
mail ctg@gmail.com
msg 56546
name efe
phone 65465
url g-t-plumbers-910
Source
url=g-t-plumbers-910&action=service_enquiry&name=efe&mail=ctg@gmail.com&phone=65465&msg=56546

Comment: console Response blank

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, please read this page and how to use data: read it at the end of the page